# How to make Samsung Tab 2 10.1 screen always on?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung, screen, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

In settings, they only give 15 secs to 30 mins options. But in my scenario, I need make it like an ads screen to present information forever, until the screen dead.

Is there any way to achieve that? Do I need unlock the bootloader?

Answer (score 1):

[Download tasker from play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)

Import the following task to tasker (save as .xml ) and then import

[Download tasker task.](http://pastebin.com/ETRN2AeM)

You will get the following screen on time 
23 hrs 59mins 59 secs

Put a profile to run everyday, so it gets repeated everyday.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[Wake Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl) does the job without going through extra setup (Tasker) and is tiny in size. Just use FULL_WAKE_LOCK to stay awake and NO_LOCK to disable.

Comment: Thank you. I have written a line of code to force the app wake up the tab.